# Load react script after all the HTML gets rendered in webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a webpage with most of the html written inside `<script type="text/template"></script>` inside this html I have a div in which my react script is supposed to render a component. The HTML inside the `type="text/template"` is being rendered with a javascript code that I have no control on.

When I add a reference to my react script inside the `head` of the page or event at the bottom of the `body` I always get

> Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM
>   element.

How can I load the react script after all the HTML gets rendered so it will find the node where to render its component

**UPDATE**

this script is being rendered with some javascript code that I have no control on

```
<script type="text/template">
  <div>
   <ul class="new-component-template" id="xblocklist" >
    <!-- the react script is supposed to render here -->
   </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

this react script gets loaded before the script above so I get a

> Target container is not a DOM element. 
>   error

```
var ListXblocks = React.createClass({

  componentWillMount: function(){
     this.setState({Problemstyle: this.props.Problemstyle})
     fetch('http://192.168.33.10:8002/XBlocks/')
     .then(result=>result.json())
     .then(result=> {
       this.setState({items:result})
     })
   },

  render:function(){
    return(

      <div>
        {
          this.state.items.map((item)=>{return(
            <li className="editor-manual" key={item.title}>
              <button type="button" className="button-component" data-category="problem" data-boilerplate="">
                <span className="name">{item.description}</span>
              </button>

            </li>)})

          }
      </div>

    );

  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<ListXblocks/>, document.getElementById('xblocklist'));
```

Comment: I'm failing to understand your question. Maybe show some code to give us context?

Comment: @AndrewLi i updated my post with some code